# Electric potential infinite box

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential

I have a question about separation of variables to calculate the electric potential.

In the picture below the potential is only on the top of the box, which is infinite in the $z$-direction. What are the solutions of differential equations?

Griffiths has an example but the potential is zero everywhere expcet on the sides of the box, which is also infinte in the $z$-direction, in that case $X(x)$ is exponential and $Y(y)$ is sine and cosine. I tried to used the same solutions in the first situations but the result doesn't seem correct. Which logic do we use when separating the variables and choosing the solutions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint: If the vertical boundaries were at 0 and 1 (rather that $\pm c/2$) you could multiply  the Fourier sine expansion
$$
1= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac 4{(2n+1)\pi}\sin[(2n+1)\pi x], \quad x \in [0,1]
$$
by $V_0$ 
to match the boundary condition at both the top edge *and* the vertical sides.

Comment: Your answer would have greater value if you showed *why* your expression is true. Also, replace $x$ by $\xi =\frac{x}{c}$.

Comment: I am sorry I didnt get it, do you mean solve like the boundaries are between 0 and 1 and multiply the solution of this expression? And why?

Comment: No I mean that you have to shift and rescale the $x$ in my formula to make $[0,1]\to [-c/a,c/2]$ and then, of course, replace  any $\sin[k(x+c/2)]$  by a suitable combination of $e^{\pm ky} \sin[k(x+c/2)]$ so as to satisfy $V=0$ on the lower boundary.

Comment: @Gert I don't want to give greater details, as then I am solving Ana's hw problem. As to *why* my formula  is true, it  is the standard Fourier sine expansion of $1$ in the unit interval, You just insert unity into the formula for the Fourier coeffcients. A student studying boundary-value problems must surely know Fourier methods.

Comment: @mikestone I am so sorry, I though I had understood the previous examples that I have studied but I dont get it, there is something that isnt clicking. My doubt goes back to the beginning, when you separate the variables and choose a constant, depending on the situation X(x) and Y(y) have different solutions, but i dont seem to get why. I just started this topic and for some reason I am having such a hard time understanding.

Comment: Look at the discussion of your problem on page 231 in our in our book http://www.goldbart.gatech.edu/PostScript/MS_PG_book/bookmaster.pdf

Comment: It may also be useful to look at the discssion of the Fourier sine series for $1$ in $L^2[0,1]$ on and around page 64 in our book.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your knowledge about fourier methods is at the level of an average second semester, i will try to sketch the method you use to solve such a problem.

So you already seem to know that you are searching for a solution of the poisson equation

\begin{align}
\nabla^2 \phi = \frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial y^2}= 0 \quad\text{, since }\rho(\vec{r}) = 0.
\end{align}

Wich is a partial differential equation and these guys are in general very hard to solve. So you are using an Ansatz in which the potential $\phi(x, y)$ seperates in a product of a function $X(x)$ and a function $Y(y)$. So you get:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} X(x)Y(y) + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} X(x)Y(y)= 0
\end{align}

which implies

\begin{align}
\frac 1 X \frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial x^2} = - \frac 1 Y\frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial y^2} .
\end{align}

So you see the left side  of the equation is only dependend on $x$ and the right side is only dependent on $y$. So to be equal for all $x, y$ they both have to be constant. So you choose now a constant lets name it $\alpha^2$, you also could choose just $\alpha$ as your constant but since you see that you differentiate your function twice it is handy to choose $\alpha^2$. So you now have tow differential equations:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial x^2} = \alpha ^2 X\\
\frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial x^2} = - \alpha ^2 Y
\end{align}

for each of them you should already know a good Ansatz. But remember that in order to get a general solution to your problem you have to consider that since these differential eqautions are linear the sum of solutions is still a solution to your equation.

If you have chosen an Ansatz you use your boundary conditions

\begin{align}
\phi( \frac c 2, y) &= 0 \\
\phi( -\frac c 2, y) &= 0 \\
\phi( x, 0 ) &= 0 \\
\phi( x, d ) &= \phi_0
\end{align}

to "specify" your solution.

I hope this helps :).

Comment: Thank you so much